# SQL Server : count the number of different spellings of same word - case sensitivity

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

How do I construct a SQL Server query for the number of different spellings of the same word?

For example if in a column there are these elements:

```
"Bicycle", 
"BICycle", 
"BiCYCLE", 
"Bicycle"
```

I should get 3 as a result.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a case-sensitive collation, you can simply do:

```
select lower(col), count(distinct col)
from t
group by lower(col);
```

If the collation for the column is case insensitive, then you can change it in the query:

```
select lower(col), count(distinct col collate Latin1_General_CS_AS)
from t
group by lower(col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do by changing collation,it's case insensitive by default so you can do it with below code

```
SELECT <column_name> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY <column_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST as a Case sensitive collation:

```
select count(distinct cast([column] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2   as nvarchar(50)))
FROM [table]
```